# How to add custom footer template for product view page in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2

How to add custom footer template for product view page in magento2.

How to do that.
Thanks.

**Update:**

```
 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::html/footer/trustworthy.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'trust.shy'
```

**In default.xml:**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="trust.shy" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/trustworthy.phtml" after="subscribe.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Added template in following path /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/OX/shy/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer/trustworthy.phtml**

Comment: you want to template add in footer above?

Comment: I need to add support.ptml in footer

Comment: means you add this file in above footer container right?

Comment: Yes ............